# Firestore save timestamps in seconds and nanoseconds

Tags: javascript

In a function that intercepts a creation of a new object in my firestore, I need to save timestamp. But I want to save this value not in this format:

> Thu Jan 17 2019 17:10:45 GMT+0000 (UTC)

but divided in seconds and nanoseconds. This result came from this function:

```
createdAt: new Date()
```

or another result, not available like:

> .sv: "timestamp"

from this function:

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

What I need to use to obtain seconds and nanoseconds?

Comment: What is your expected format for the "seconds and nanoseconds"?

Comment: How (and why) do you want to get nanoseconds? `Date.now() * 1000` is obviously not really accurate.

Comment: Not really possible anyway, but... I'm curious as to the format question and why we are showing "seconds" and "nanoseconds" and completely by passing "milli" and "micro".

Comment: I think OP means milliseconds :P that's what happens when you don't pay attention in science class people

Comment: @Terry - that is my instinct too, at least that is achievable :-)

Comment: I would like to know only if there are methods to maintain maximum precision and the choice of the number of digits without write a custom method

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a timestamp in milliseconds, the correct way is:

```
createdAt: Date.now()
```

If you really want more precision, there is:

```
window.performance.now()
```

It gives milliseconds since page load, and also:

```
window.performance.timeOrigin
```

gives timestamp in milliseconds at page load, so you could get nanoseconds like that:

```
createdAt: Math.round((window.performance.timeOrigin+window.performance.now())*1000000)
```